# Function check-up exercise

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers

I want to make sure I did everything correctly, so here's the exercise:

> Given $P$ the set of positive prime numbers and be $S = \mathbb N^* - \{1\}$. $\forall n \in S,\ \pi(n)$ is the set of the primes $\in P$ which divide $n$, $\ \ p_n = \min\ \pi(n)$, $\ \ q_n = \max\ \pi(n)$. Given also the application: $$f: n \in S \longrightarrow (p_n, q_n) \in P \times P$$
>   $\rho$ is the following relation order defined on $S$: $$\forall n, m \in S, n\  \rho\ m \iff n = m \text{ or } (p_n\mid p_m\text{ and } q_n < q_m).$$

**Questions**:

1. Is $f$ injective? Is $f$ surjective?
2. What is $f(S)$?
3. Determine in $(S, \rho)$ minimum, maximum, minimals and maximals.
4. Is $(S, \rho)$ a lattice?

**My answers**:

1. $f$ is **NOT injective** because $f(2) = f(4) = (2,2)$ but $2 \neq 4$. 
   $f$ is **NOT surjective** because $\not\exists n \in S: f(n) = (3,2)$
2. $f(S) = \{(p, q) \in P \times P: p \leq q\}$
3. *2 is minimal*.
   There are **no maximals** and no minimum because a prime that can be divided by every prime does NOT exist.
4. $(S, \rho)$ is **not a lattice** because $\not\exists \inf\{2,3\}$

I really appreciate if any of you can correct me if I'm wrong or not about these replies. Thank you a lot.